# How to compress columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, compression, innodb

I have a table which stores e-mail correspondences. Every time someone
replies, the whole body of the trail is also included and saved into
the database (and I need it that way because the amount of application
level changes to rectify that are going to be too high).

The size of the `mail` text column is `10000`. But, I am having trouble storing text more than that. As I am not sure, how many correspondences can occur, I don't know what a good number will be for the column.

The engine is `InnoDB`. Can I use some kind of columnar compression technique in `MySQL` to avoid increasing the size of the column?

And, what if I go ahead and increase the varchar column to, say, 20000. The table has about 2 million records. Will that be a good thing to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for MySQL [COMPRESS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//encryption-functions.html#function_compress) and [UNCOMPRESS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//encryption-functions.html#function_uncompress) function to compress data for storage and retrieval respectively.

Also look at [InnoDB Compression Usage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression-usage.html).

Comment: Using JPA query at the backend. Will have to look for a solution to extract the data in the same way because the data is a trail of emails or twitter feed or whatnot.

Comment: `COMPRESS()` won't work unless you change to `VARBINARY` or `BLOB`.  (I assume that is not allowed.)  InnoDB compression may be the only option; but that will give you only 2x improvement.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the data doesn't  need editing, you can use the archive engine.

Comment: All the tables are on InnoDB. I am not going to change that.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is **specific to Percona**

Percona introduced a *compressed* column format a while ago. That you can use on CREATE or ALTERs

```
CREATE TABLE test_compressed (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    value MEDIUMTEXT COLUMN_FORMAT COMPRESSED
 );
```

Reference: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/flexibility/compressed_columns.html

Answer (score 1):

For me the best way to use text data compression is to use a **Percona** compressed column format.

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` MODIFY `mail` TEXT COLUMN_FORMAT COMPRESSED NOT NULL;
```

I've tested compression on table used as cache, storing mainly HTML data, the size decreased from 620 MB to 110.6MB.

I think you should consider using TEXT type instead of long VARCHAR. 
Data fields are stored separately from innodb clustered index and it can affect and probably improve the performance of your database.

Comment: Somehow this does not work. Have to remove "COLUMN_FORMAT" to make it work.

Comment: It's Percona specific function and do not work in Oracle MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different options:

- Wait for the RFE to add column compression to MySQL (see https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=106541) - unlikely this will ever be done
- Use application level compression and decompression - much more work involved in doing this
- Rely on MySQL's compress and uncompress functions to do this for you (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress) - these are not reliable as they depend on how MySQL was compiled (zlib or not) - and they don't give great results a lot of the time
- Don't worry about the file size as disk space is cheap and simply change the column type to TEXT (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)
- Often the best option if disk space is your main concern is changing the table to be compressed using: `ALTER TABLE t1 ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED;` - for emails this can give very good compression and if need be it can be tuned for even better compression for your particular workload (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-compression-tuning.html)