# Unknown compression method

Tags: c#, zip, compression

In database I have blob column with chart data.

The data was compressed, unfortunately I tried different solutions and none worked. What type of compression is this? no one from tested not work. I tested zip, bzip, zlib, gzip2 etc

Here is example from database:

```
5a 49 50 08 52 00 00 78 9c ed 9c 0b 54 56 55 fe (...)
```

Full binary: https://www.paste.org/97372

After converting to ascii, the first three characters are "ZIP" (the fourth character is always random which means to me this is the end of header) but I can't find this type of compression.

I checked other blob's and I find "78 9c" always on the same position. Then I try ZLIB.NET:

```
 public static void DecompressData(byte[] inData, out byte[] outData)
    {
        using (MemoryStream outMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (ZOutputStream outZStream = new ZOutputStream(outMemoryStream))
        using (Stream inMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(inData))
        {
            CopyStream(inMemoryStream, outZStream);
            outZStream.finish();
            outData = outMemoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static void CopyStream(System.IO.Stream input, System.IO.Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2000]; //example
        int len;
        while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, 2000)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        output.Flush();
    }
```

Unfortunately, the same error appears:

> zlib.ZStreamException: „inflating: unknown compression method”

Comment: And what is your question exactly?

Comment: `5a 49` isn't a standard magic header. "*If needed I can send full size BLOB from db (~6500 bytes)*" -- well the small snippet you provided is useless I'm afraid, so that's your only chance.

Comment: The question is: What type of compression is this, no one from tested not work. I tested zip, bzip, zlib, gzip2 etc

Comment: I suspect the first few bytes were added by your application (since they're non-standard). Try stripping them off, and trying again.

Comment: Full binary: https://www.paste.org/97372

Comment: "*the fourth character is always random which means to me this is the end of header* ... *checked other blob's and I find "78 9c" always on the same position*" That means the header extends at least to `78 9c`. Maybe the 4th character is related to the length of the compressed / original content.

Comment: There is a very good selection of file signatures here - in numerical order of first bytes. https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html  I had a quick scan up to "54 55 56" values (4 after 78 9c) & could not find any match. A conversion to ASCII gave on obvious indication of contents.

Comment: There is always the possibility the compression of the BLOB field is a proprietary format for the database & the field needs to be explicitly uncompressed with the appropriate function : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910670/how-to-compress-columns-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

The `78 9c` is the header of a zlib stream. Indeed, the 10,752 bytes from there on is a valid zlib stream, which decompresses to 21,000 bytes. The four bytes after the "ZIP" and before the `78 9c`, which is `08 52 00 00` is the number 21,000 in little-endian order.

So your format is "ZIP", followed by the uncompressed size in four bytes in little-endian order, followed by a zlib stream.